# POST error with missing body when use XMLHttpRequest but works with Fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I have the following post function

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
function post(url, params, callback, method='POST') {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open(method, url, true);
  http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
  http.onload = function() {
    console.log(http.status) <---- 500
    console.log(http.responseText) <----'ERROR: An 'ipAddr' must be provided in the request body.',
    callback(http);
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(params)) <--- print {"ipAddr":"175.00.00.00","params":"params_string"}
  http.send(JSON.stringify(params));
}
```

keep getting 500 with responseText saying `ipAddr` is missing
but I am passing in `ipAddr` in the request body...what am I missing?

by the way the endpoint I am trying to reach works. Confrimed with curl

```
curl -i --header tion/json" -d '{"ipAddr": "175.00.00.00", "params": "params_string"}' --request POST https://my.endpoint/run
```

this returns me a 200 result.

---

**update...**

switch to using fetch, then it worked? not sure why, its the same content translate over

```
var fetch = require("node-fetch");
function post(url, params, callback, method='POST') {
  // request options
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(params),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  }

  // send post request
  fetch(url, options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce it without the code of server-side.

Comment: I added a little snippet

Comment: Did you get the correct response in this mid-layer? You pass `req.body` to `post` function as `params`, but you didn't use it.

Comment: no :( seems like the error occur when post finish. the console.log() logs out the err in the `onload` listener

Comment: it works with fetch for some reason...but its the same header, body, and method